# runtime error. there is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-1'

Tags: django, django-views, runtime-error, python-multithreading, telethon

i followed this tutorial https://python.gotrained.com/scraping-telegram-group-members-python-telethon/, and the code ran successfully on a single python script. so i decided to implement the same code into django views.py. form.py, html templates and urls.py are properly connected. whenever i runserver and enter details it raises runtime error saying "*There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-1'*."

**views.py**

````
import asyncio

from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient

from .form import DetailForm,CodeForm
from .models import Detail,Code

# Create your views here.

def home(request):
    form = DetailForm
    context = {'form':form}
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = DetailForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            details = Detail.objects.all().last()
            api_id = int(details.api_id)
            api_hash = details.api_hash
            phone_number = details.phone_number
            loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
            client = TelegramClient(phone_number, api_id, api_hash, loop=loop)
            client.connect()
            if not client.is_user_authorized():
                client.send_code_request(phone_number)
            # global client, phone_number
        return redirect('code')
    return render(request, 'teleapp/home.html', context)


def codeview(request):
    code=CodeForm
    # codemodel = Code.objects.all().last()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        codes = CodeForm(request.POST)
        if codes.is_valid():
            codes.save()
            #what next...
            return redirect('scrapy')
    context = {'code':code}
    return render(request, 'teleapp/code.html', context)


def scrappy(request):
    details = Detail.objects.all().last()
    context = {'details':details}
    return render(request, 'teleapp/scrappy.html', context)```

**error raised**
Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\telegram\venv\lib\site-packages\django\c
ore\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\telegram\venv\lib\site-packages\django\c
ore\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\telegram\venv\lib\site-packages\django\c
ore\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\telegram\scrapy\teleapp\views.py", line
24, in home
    client.connect()
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\telegram\venv\lib\site-packages\telethon
\sync.py", line 35, in syncified
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\asyncio\ev
ents.py", line 694, in get_event_loop
    return get_event_loop_policy().get_event_loop()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 602, in get_event_loop
    % threading.current_thread().name)
RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-2'.
````